# Difference of 2 calculated fields in Pivot in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a raw data which is on account level with current balance, total balance and sales amount
My formula reads:
Total DSO : `Total balance * 92 / 3monthBilling Amount`
Best DSO : `Current Balance * 92 / 3monthBilling Amount`

I wanted the grouping on month level to get the overall DSO, Best DSO
So i used the formula:
Total DSO :  `Total balance * 92 / Sales Amount OVER (Month)`
Best DSO : `Current Balance * 92 / Sales Amount OVER (Month)`

The above 2 works perfectly but I want a 3rd field called `Remaining DSO = Total DSO-Best DSO`

So in Spotfire, when I insert a calculated column to the pivot
saying `Remaining = Total DSO - Best DSO` I don't get a correct value.

Then I tried `Remaining = Total DSO - Best DSO OVER (month)` and `Remaining = (Total balance-current balance)*92 / Sales OVER (Month)` both which also produced an incorrect value.

Simply, I want a difference of the two fields (but to be done on the pivot level like excel and not raw data level)

Comment: Do you have any sample data to help in reproducing? Also take a look at the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to better format your questions.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the markdown.. I'll keep a note of that.. plus since i didnt have enough points here,  i couldnt upload a raw data file which I had. However I have now solved this. I did the "Remaining field" in excel itself and then loaded the value in Spotfire , dividing it by sales OVER Month.. Thanks anyways for ur help here ..